# Eloquent JavaScript ch5 - "Your own loop" solution (loop vs recursion)

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

I really did overflow the stack on my first try, but then I put the return statement (see comment in code) without an argument and it worked.

**Task:**

Write a higher-order function loop that provides something like a for loop statement. It takes a value, a test function, an update function, and a body function. Each iteration, it first runs the test function on the current loop value, and stops if that returns false. Then it calls the body function, giving it the current value. And finally, it calls the update function to create a new value, and starts from the beginning.

*When defining the function, you can use a regular loop to do the actual looping.*

***I didn't use loop.***

**Book Solution**

```
function loop(start, test, update, body) {
   for (let value = start; test(value); value = update(value)) {
     body(value);
   }
 }

 loop(3, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log);
 // → 3
 // → 2
 // → 1
```

**My Solution (kept my original function parameter names)**

```
function loop(value, test, update, execute){
  if (test(value)) execute(value);
  else return // prevents stack overflow?
  return loop(update(value),test,update,execute)


}
loop(3, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log);
// → 3
// → 2
// → 1
```

Did I just made the console output the same thing, or will my solution do the same thing in a real-environment program?

I ask, because I'm not sure if I actually solved it with recursion, or just made the console output the same thing. This will help me feel better about myself, since I'm a noob JS learner. Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*made the console output the same thing*".

Comment: In other words - Is my solution a real solution, or just luck - as you have mentioned in your other comment. Thanks man, appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the correct recursive implementation for the task. You didn't just hit the correct output by chance.

The `else return` is a bit odd though. I would have written either

```
function loop(value, test, update, execute) {
  if (test(value)) {
    execute(value);
    return loop(update(value), test, update, execute);
  } // else stop
}
```

or

```
function loop(value, test, update, execute) {
  if (!test(value)) return; // stop
  execute(value);
  return loop(update(value), test, update, execute);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Initializer

The book solution creates a `value` variable and initializes it with start. In your case this happens automatically when you pass your first parameter. So far the two approaches are equivalent.

#### Test

The `for` loop calls `test(value)` as cycle `test`. Your approach does something similar, but calling `test` is the test for recursion. So far the two approaches are equivalent.

#### Cycle block

The `for` loop calls `body(value)`. Your approach calls `execute(value)`. So far the two approaches are equivalent.

#### The update

`value` is updated in the cycle after each iteration. The same happens in your code when you pass `update(value)` in your recursive call. So far the two approaches are equivalent.

#### Are they really equivalent?

Algorithmically, yes. Technically, no. Your recursive approach calls the `function` several times and uses the stack (of the memory) to store the `function` calls. In the case of a too large numbers of `test`, your code will crash. So, you have successfully implemented a recursive version of the book example (yay!) but you should try to avoid recursion in most cases.